# change listview color in jQuery-Mobile 1.4.5

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have some Problems changing the `background-color` of one particular `listitem` in my `jQuery-Mobile` `Listview`.

Every `listitem` has it's own ID.
I want to change just one.

Please help me :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read How do I ask  a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible way to do that:

```css
#item-2 .ui-btn {
  background-color: aliceblue !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Friday, October 8, 2010 <span class="ui-li-count">2</span></li>
        <li id="item-1">
          <a href="index.html">
            <h2>Stephen Weber</h2>
            <p><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p>
            <p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>6:24</strong>PM</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="item-2">
          <a href="index.html">
            <h2>jQuery Team</h2>
            <p><strong>Boston Conference Planning</strong></p>
            <p>In preparation for the upcoming conference in Boston, we need to start gathering a list of sponsors and speakers.</p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>9:18</strong>AM</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">Thursday, October 7, 2010 <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></li>
        <li id="item-3">
          <a href="index.html">
            <h2>Avery Walker</h2>
            <p><strong>Re: Dinner Tonight</strong></p>
            <p>Sure, let's plan on meeting at Highland Kitchen at 8:00 tonight. Can't wait!</p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>4:48</strong>PM</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```